# How to change screen by calling a method in Python Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy and I want to change my screen by clicking the image. I used the ButtonBehavior and call the on_press method of my class ImageButton but I can't figure it out what code to put. I tried **on_press: screen_manager.current = 'window1'** on my kivy file but its not working

**Python Code**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class Window1(Screen):
    pass

class Window2(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        # what to call

class Phone(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Phone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**kv file**

```
<Phone>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        WindowManager:
            id: screen_manager
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
            anchor_y: 'top'
            transition: FadeTransition()
            Window1:
            Window2:

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 228, 241, 254, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            ImageButton:
                source: 'pic1.png'
                on_press: self.on_press()
            ImageButton:
                source: 'pic2.png'
                on_press: self.on_press()


<Window1>:
    name: 'window1'
    Label:
        text: 'Window1'
<Window2>:
    name: 'window2'
    Label:
        text: 'Window2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some one help me on this.. what im missing is in my kv file i should put

> on_press: app.root.ids._screen_manager.current = 'window1'

Here is the explanation

When the kv code is parsed, the id fields go into a dict called ids, that stores pointers to the widget objects.

Each kivy rule has a sperate name space for ids.

Breaking it down:

app.root.ids.screen_manager

app is your app

root is the root widget, Phone

ids is the dict of ids defined at the root level

Credit for Elliot Garbus